# Changing C variables from python?

Tags: python, c, api

I have an embedded python interpreter in my program. I'd like to export a module with values defined in my program and be able to change them from a python script. e.g.
in c:

`int x = 1;`

in python:

`import embedded
embedded.x = 2`

in c:

`printf("%d",x);`

output: 
`2`

Is this possible or do I have to export functions to change anything in c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to export functions, but the easiest way to do this would be to use [`PyModule_GetDict()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/module.html#PyModule_GetDict) with [`PyDict_GetItemString()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/dict.html#PyDict_GetItemString) to get the value assigned to the `x` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actively check the value of a PyObject in your C code, I think you need to export functions to modify the representation in C. I'm no expert, but I don't think there's an automatic mapping.